# Removing empty key-value pairs in .properties file

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, properties-file

I have a few `.properties` files like:

```
button.upload=
classification.button.classifier.detail.create=Klassifikator erstellen
classification.button.classifier.detail.delete=L\u00F6schen
button.toggleall=
button.update=
```

I need to deliver clean files without the keys with empty values. The result should be like this:

```
classification.button.classifier.detail.create=Klassifikator erstellen
classification.button.classifier.detail.delete=L\u00F6schen
```

Is there a regex, function or workaround to do this in Sublime Text? Thanks.

Comment: Matching lines with empty values using `^[^=]*=\s*$(\n|$)` regex and replace with empty string? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F58iCq/1)

Comment: Just to add: press `Ctrl + H` and in find area put regex mentioned by @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi and replace area leave empty and press `Replace All`

Comment: To not replace existing empty lines, try `^[^\r\n=]+=[ \t]*$(?:\r?\n|\r)?` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bk4P4o/1)

Comment: Thanks @PushpeshKumarRajwanshibut !